# How to draw a triangle on a sphere surface where each angle has 90°?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The problem statement says this:

*Explain how to draw a triangle, on a sphere surface, where each of its angles 90 degrees. In this right triangle,  do the hypotenuse and the sides (adjacent and opposite) satisfy the condition $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$? Explain why this does not violate the Pythagoras's Theorem.*

I'm trying to draw the triangle and this is one of the attempts:

[image: Photo 1]

and

[image: Photo 2]

and finally

[image: Photo 3]

Did I started correctly? Or what kind of drawing manipulation I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is indeed a visual demonstration of how to draw a triangle with three right angles on a spherically curved surface.   You are on the correct trail.

Can you put what you did into words?

So, if the sphere is of radius $r$, what must the lengths of each of the triangle's three sides be?

Does $a^2+b^2 = c^2$ , and if not, what's going on?   (What assumption(s) does Pythagorus Theorem require that drawing on a sphere might violate?)